# Iterate over a list in a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a list in a class, but instead only the first member of the list is being printed out to the console. How do print each element?

```
class CodeManager(object):
    """Separates the input string into individual characters in a list"""

    characters = []

    def __init__(self, stringCode):
        self.stringCode = stringCode

    def LoopThroughList(self):

        self.characters = list(self.stringCode.upper())
        for chars in self.characters:
            return chars
```

And then I create a class object in my main Python file:

```
code = CodeManager.CodeManager("Hello my name is Callum")
print (code.LoopThroughList())
```

Comment: you're returning , hence first element in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning after the first iteration:

```
for chars in self.characters:
        return chars # ends loop
```

If you want to see all the characters, use print or yield and iterate over `code.LoopThroughList()`

```
for chars in self.characters:
        print(chars)
```

Or `yield` and make the method a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
 for chars in self.characters:
        yield chars
```

Then:

```
for ch in code.LoopThroughList():
    print(ch)
```

Using yield will actually allow you to use each character returned which is probably closer to what you are trying to do in your own code.

If you just want to see each char outputted on a new line, you can use str.join:

```
self.characters = list(self.stringCode.upper())
        return "\n".join(self.characters)
```

You also don't need to call list on  `self.stringCode.upper()`, you can iterate directly over a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is `return`ing the first character. A `return` statement will block the execution of the remaining iterations of the loop.

You probably wanted to use `print` instead of `return`:

```
def loop_through_list(self):
    self.characters = list(self.stringCode.upper())
    for char in self.characters:
        print(char)
```

Used as:

```
code = CodeManager.CodeManager("Hello my name is Callum")
code.loop_through_list()
```

---

Moreover, your definition of `characters = []` in the `class` is pretty useless. You are *shadowing* the class attribute inside the method call.

Answer (score 0):

you're returning , hence first element in the list.

```
class CodeManager(object):
    """Separates the input string into individual characters in a list"""

    characters = []

    def __init__(self, stringCode):
        self.stringCode = stringCode

    def LoopThroughList(self):
        self.characters = list(self.stringCode.upper())
        for chars in self.characters:
            print chars

code = CodeManager("Hello my name is Callum")
code.LoopThroughList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def LoopThroughList(self):
    return [chars for chars in self.stringCode.upper()]
```

This will return a list of all the characters in the `stringCode` variable

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. List comprehension works with a slight modification:

```
class CodeManager(object):
"""Separates the input string into individual characters in a list"""

    characters = []

    def __init__(self, stringCode):
        self.stringCode = stringCode
        self.characters = stringCode.upper()

    def LoopThroughList(self):
        return [chars for chars in self.stringCode.upper().split()]


code = CodeManager("Hello my name is Callum")
print (code.LoopThroughList())
```

> ['HELLO','MY','NAME','IS','CALUM']

Or if you want this:

```
class CodeManager(object):

characters = []

def __init__(self, stringCode):
    self.stringCode = stringCode
    self.characters = stringCode.upper()

def LoopThroughList(self):
    return [chars for chars in self.stringCode.upper()]


code = CodeManager("Hello my name is Callum")
print (code.LoopThroughList())
```

> ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', 'M', 'Y', ' ', 'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', ' ', 'I', 'S', ' ', 'C', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'U', 'M']

your characters variable is a class variable, not an instance variable (there is a difference).